# Reading strings from stdin or argument in Haskell CLI

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to build a Haskell CLI that can either read in strings from stdin or from arguments like so:

```
cat colors-multi-line | colorshift -d 10

colorshift -d 10 "#FFFFFF"
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You do what you just said. You either read something from the command line using `getArgs` or you read something from stdin using `getLine`. You've not said when you want it to be one or the other - but basically, just apply whatever criteria you have for this.

Comment: If the user doesn't provide anything to stdin when the program starts, I'd like it to expect an argument with their input. If no input is found from either, the help screen should display.

Comment: You can import `getArgs` `System.Environment`, and do pattern matching on the result of `getArgs`.

```
import System.Environment
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [flag, n] -> _
    [flag, n, color] ->
    _ -> _ 
```

Comment: @CarolynSaunders You can't check if anything is on STDIN - it could come with any amount of delay. Imagine `incredibly_long_running_application | your_program`

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries to handle CLI argument parsing.  [`optparse-applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) is the one with which I'm most familiar.  [`getLine`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine) and `getContents` in `Prelude`read from `STDIN`.